# Company Pages Gallery Images Load Slowly

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I was browsing through the [SproutSocial](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/sproutsocial?c=1LzRBKLOIe) company page. It's beautifully designed, **but when I got to the gallery part** and clicked on a different photo, it took a good **1-2 seconds** for the other image to load, and there wasn't an indicator that something was happening.

Could we add a loading indicator and/or compress the images?

Comment: No repo here; what browser are you using? On Chrome 30.0.1599.101 on Mac OS X 10.8.5 the gallery images load nice and fast. All images are hosted on the http://i.stack.imgur.com/ CDN, which hosts all images across the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Is this a recurring problem for you, intermittent or just a one time issue?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am using Chrome 30.0.1599.69 on Mac OS X 10.8.5.

From the Millenium hotel, where ping and bandwidth is generally good, I can get consistent results. See the following screenshots: http://imgur.com/a/st77R. The first one shows the case where only one of the images downloaded slowly. The second one shows where x images out of y loaded slowly.

Comment: @NickLarsen reproduced here (Israel), one full second for 600Kb image - preloading all images should solve this, is it feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added preloading to the gallery images.  This won't solve the issue of some of the images failing to load, but it should speed up general case.  I cannot really reproduce it here, so let me know if the experience is still bad and I will add some kind of loading animation.